# ViewPoint Control does not behave as expected [helix-3d-toolkit]

Tags: helix-3d-toolkit

I have built successfully some of the examples (teapot, torus, tube). I have three questions related to all of them.

1. I can use the zoom control by keyboard+mouse Cntrl+RightClick
   combination. However, when I use the Cntrl+LeftClick for adhusting
   ViewPoint, the ViewPoint jumps to top view and cannot be changed
   afterwards in all examples. Perhaps this issue is related to
   questions below.
2. All examples refer to an assembly called "ExampleBrowser". I had
   to comment out in the cs file as I cannot find this assembly. Could
   you please let me know how to fix this problem. I am using Visual
   Studio (VS) 2017.

In all examples I tried, there is a line like: `[Example(null, "Shows Borromean rings using the TubeVisual3D.")]` which causes VS to give error. I had to comment out this line too. Could somebody let me know the reason this line is not accepted by VS?

Comment: Please split these into three entirely separate questions.  Also, question 3 is not something which could probably be answered without more context.  Number 1 is probably not a code question but rather a software question and therefore not relevant to Stack Overflow.  Regarding the examples, can you clarify what examples you're talking about?  Do you mean the SDK examples?

Comment: I think I resolved the issue#1). Zoom is controlled by mouse wheel. In order to rotate the object, one has to move inside the circle while holding to Cntrl.

I will post the two other issues separately as suggested.

Thanks in advance.

ikonuk